# Why am I getting "OpenID not found"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

Whenever I try to login to stackoverflow the normal way I keep getting an error message saying openID not found. I had to login through facebook to ask this question and normally I don't trust Facebook login. What is OpenID and how do I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a brief period earlier where our OpenID provider (openid.stackexchange.com) was unavailable.

This has been fixed, and everything should be functioning correctly again.